# Can we use other path intead of usr/bin?

Tags: ftp, cpanel

Im using wallpaper script in my site and it need ImageMagic or Gdlibrary to be installed on server.Server path should be usr/bin/imagemagic or usr/bin/gdlibrary. those scripts must be intalled by server administration but when i informed them they say currently they do not install other scripts/softwares on the server! Now i want to know is there any way to install without using usr/bin path. Is there any way to intall it myself i have access to ftp but there's no path called usr/bin..please help me! Thank You!

Comment: This would probably be better placed on [SU](http://superuser.com/), as it seems like your best bet lies with command line tools like [chroot(8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot).

Answer (score 0):

compile the source code yourself, and specify the `--prefix=/the/path/you/want`